# Estimation of mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution in R.problem with the "optim" function

Tags: r, normal-distribution, optimization

i'm trying to write a code in r in order to find the maximum likelihood(not the log-likelihood) values for a univariate normal distribution. I know that there are other methods but a deep understand of numerical optimization is needed for me for further works. When i call the 'optim' function it seems it doesn't iterate at all and return the values that i passed as initial parameters. This doesn't happen if i pass to the optimizer the function that instead computes the log-likelihood. Any idea why? I cannot see where my error is. I could just say that maybe the product of the  densities is too much close to the zero and the calculator can't handle it. Here is my code.Thanks a lot!

```
set.seed(123);
x=rnorm(10, mean = 2, sd = 5)

LikeNormUnivar<-function(param,data){
  mu=param[1];
  sdev=param[2];
  densityvector=dnorm(data, mean = mu, sd = sdev, log = FALSE)
  like=prod(densityvector)
  return(-like)
}

theta.start = c(2,4)
ans = optim(par=theta.start, fn=LikeNormUnivar, data=x,control=list(trace=TRUE),
            method="BFGS")
ans$par
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was going on by adding the line `cat(mu,sdev,like,"\n")` at an appropriate place in the function to see what was going on.  Basically, on the scale on which the `BFGS` is estimating derivatives by finite differences, there's not enough variation. Setting `retol=1e-16` in the `control` list works.  Better, try minimizing the negative *log* likelihood ... and fitting on the log-standard-deviation scale is also a good idea, e.g.

```
LikeNormUnivar <- function(param,data){
  mu=param[1]
  sdev=exp(param[2])
  loglik=dnorm(data, mean = mu, sd = sdev, log = TRUE)
  return(-sum(loglik))
}
```

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1)